# q-ary lattices - proof of dual upto scale

Tags: lattice-crypto

Two lattices are defined as following:
\begin{align}
\Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)} & = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^m: A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}\text{  mod }q\} \\
\Lambda_q{(A)} & = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^m: \mathbf{x} = A^T\mathbf{s} \text{  mod }q \text{ for some } \mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q\}.
\end{align}
T.S.T.

1. $\Lambda_q{(A)} = q \cdot \Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)}^*$, where $\Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)}^*$ is the dual of $\Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)}$, and
2. $\Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)} = q \cdot \Lambda_q{(A)}^*$, where $\Lambda_q{(A)}^*$ is the dual of $\Lambda_q{(A)}$.

In most references I see that it is left as an exercise and I am not able to work out a proof.

Comment: Have you tried expending out the definition of the dual lattice ?
A trick you might need at some point is that for $x \in \mathbb R$, the property $x \in \mathbb Z$ can be equivalently re-written as $x = 0 \bmod 1$.

Comment: @LeoDucas, What do you mean exactly? Do you mean [ [Ducas-Dadush2018-lecture1](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~dadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-1.pdf) , page 3]? How can we use this notation. There is a solution in [ [SeminarLuxemborg2019](https://sp2.uni.lu/wp-content/uploads/sites/66/2019/06/DualLattice-Luca-Notarnicola.pdf), page 25] but I'm curious about your approach.